# Why is Ubuntu changing my microphone sensitivity?

Tags: 12.04, microphone

I've installed Ubuntu a few days ago. I am very satisfied with it, but there are some errors I can't fix.
There is this problem with the microphone sensitivity. When I'm skyping my friends are angry at me, because the Microphone-sensitivity is changing constantly. It's getting more sensitive until it can't get more. They even can hear cars driving along the road.
I clicked the speakers button in the upper right corner and was evebn able to see the sensitivity increase.

So if that was enough info for you, I'd be very grateful for you to answer my question xDD

Thank you in advance
Max

Comment: Isn't this a standard option to contain a constant loudness level as output from the microphone? This is a standard option in most voip programs.

Comment: Please raise just one issue per question. Ask another question about the unwanted scrolling. Also, please provide more detail for both: like when what happens. It may help people help you.

Answer (score 2):

Is the option *Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels* enabled in Skype's audio preferences? If yes, then try deselecting it.

[image]